# GIT initialization and connection to Github

Tags: git, github

I know this topic is just all over the place, and I was sincerely attempting for quite a lot of hours, and without shred of success.

My issue is that my git doesn't recognize my **own** repository. It provides me with the following error on any attempt to perform pull/push:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/danieln-juno/bugreport.git/' not found
```

Now, I did not misspell the name of the repository/URL. Also, I do have an access as I am the owner of the repository.

when I perform the command `git remote -v`, I get the correct url:

```
 origin  https://github.com/danieln-juno/bugreport.git (fetch) origin 
 https://github.com/danieln-juno/bugreport.git (push)
```

My current local folder has been initialized, of course.

I'll just add that I had Git initialized and working along GitHub, up to the point I had to do a System Reset (Not format), plus I wanted to create and use a new GitHub account.

I'm using Windows10 with MINGW64 (Git Bash).

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have manager-core as a credential helper.
Check it is the case with:

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

Check what is stored in that helper:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-manager-core get
```

If you do see your GitHub account password, instead of a [GitHub PAT (Personal Access token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), remove it, and store the token.

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=danieln-juno" | git-credential-manager-core erase

printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=danieln-juno\npassword=yourToken" | git-credential-manager-core store
```

Comment: Thank you, you were a tremendous milestone in the way to solve this matter. So much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

without VonC's answer, I wouldn't be able to solve the issue.

When I was following his steps, trying to to the following command:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-manager-core get
```

I have noticed that my former GitHub user was saved.

I have erased the credentials, from 'start button' -> 'credential manager' -> 'windows credentials' -> under 'generic credentials', remove git:https://github.com credentials.

Then, I was also performing the following command:

```
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Afterwards, I have performed:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-manager-core get
```

and performed a login authentication with GitHub.

The last steps, were as he stated:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=danieln-juno" | git-credential-manager-core erase

printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=danieln-juno\npassword=yourToken" | git-credential-manager-core store
```

VonC deserves all the credit. I just wanted to add small points that might help to future programmers. Hopefully it will help many more to come.