# Setting up gitconfig smtppass as passcmd

Tags: git, smtp

I'm just getting started with git send-mail for a sourcehut project, *so far so good*.

My current .gitconfig looks like this:

```
[user]
    email = johndoe@host.com
    name = John Doe
    signingkey = <mysignkey>
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[format]
    subjectPrefix = [PATCH]
[sendemail]
    smtpserver = smtp.johndoe.com
    smtpuser = johndoe@host.com
    smtpencryption = ssl
    smtpserverport = 465
    smtppass = my-password-in-clear-text
```

Is there a way to set `smtppass` with a `pass` + `sed` instead of having it in clear text?

I'm using `pass`, usually I'm setting it up with a passcmd `pass show host.com/johndoe.com | sed -n '3p` but I don't know how I can do that in .gitconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can directly use a `pass` command in your `.gitconfig` file. It is just a plain text file, and there's no way to execute shell commands within it.

One possible workaround is to create a script that retrieves the password from `pass`, and then use that script in the `smtppass` option.

But git send-mail would explain the configuration `[sendemail].smtppass` to *be* the password, not a command to retrieve it.

Check if using a git credential helper would help, assuming [GCM is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309):

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

(Your executable `git-credential-manager`, or `git-credential-manager-core` for older Git version, must be in your `$PATH`/`%PATH%`)

```
printf "host=smtp.johndoe.com:465\nusername=johndoe@host.com\nprotocol=smtp" | git-credential-manager store $(pass show host.com/johndoe.com | sed -n '3p')
```

If GCM is not available, you can, as suggested [in your thread](https://lists.sr.ht/%7Esircmpwn/sr.ht-discuss/%3C87mt2tmsjp.fsf%40thanosapollo.com%3E), [use a custom helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_custom_helpers):

```
[credential "smtp://smtp.johndoe.com:465"]
    helper = "!f() { echo username=johndoe@host.com; echo \"password=$(pass show xenrox/mail.xenrox.net/thorben | sed -n '3p')\"; }; f"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately it doesn't really accept the value from a bash script `fatal: bad config line 3 in file /<path>/get-smpt-pass` for now the only workaround that I could find is through emacs `password-store`. I will put an update tomorrow if I find a better solution.

Comment: @Thanos_Apollo OK, I have updated the answer to use the Emacs password store.

Comment: I don't think the above solution is working. Even having $(echo "password") is not accepted, so I believe we can't utilize any solution that includes this format. What I'm doing with `password-store` is having a function like ` (insert (password-store-get-field "mail.com/johndoe.com" "smtp"))` bind it to a key and then just insert it whenever I'm asked for it.  I also asked sr.ht-discuss here https://lists.sr.ht/~sircmpwn/sr.ht-discuss/%3C87mt2tmsjp.fsf%40thanosapollo.com%3E  according to their replies(as of now) I should find a way through using git-credentials.

Comment: @Thanos_Apollo True, I mention the [GCM (Git Credential Manager) here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309). You can use it to store/retrieve credentials, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74515709/6309).

Comment: @Thanos_Apollo I have rewritten the answer to use GCM.

Comment: I fixed my issue using xenrox [gitconfig](https://paste.xenrox.net/~xenrox/49cefdf456533aeadfe176f237632f2aa0a5c7fb) which is almost the same as your current reply. Thank you for your help!