# How to use git-credential-gopass with git send-email?

Tags: git, version-control, smtp, devops

I'm starting to now contribute to projects on sr.ht which typically uses [`git send-email`](https://git-send-email.io/) as part of the workflow.

I read the [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) and [git-send-email](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email). I saw [Setting up gitconfig smtppass as passcmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117242) and it seems there they used a custom helper, but that shouldn't necessary if one exists like the [credential-helpers](https://git-scm.com/doc/credential-helpers) like [git-credential-gopass](https://github.com/gopasspw/git-credential-gopass)?

This is what I have:

```
[sendemail]
    smtpserver = example.com
    smtpuser = user@example.com
    smtpencryption = ssl
    smtpserverport = 465

[credential "smtp://example.com:465"]
    username = user@example.com
    helper = gopass mail/example_email
```

I added this to my global config, password is normally returned when I type `gopass mail/example_email`. I want to avoid that annoying:

```
Password for 'smtp://user@example.com@example.com:465'
```

Prompt every time I try to send a patch.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to have only the username under `smtpuser` even if you'd normally authenticate with user@example.com otherwise what you'll get is `user@example.com@example.com`

```
[sendemail]
    smtpserver = example.com
    smtpuser = username
    smtpencryption = ssl
    smtpserverport = 465

[credential "smtp://username@example.com:465"]
    helper = gopass
```

Secondly the path needs to be:

```
.../gopass/stores/root/git/example.com_465/username.gpg
```